# Unable to run model defined function

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

Exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: The specified method 'Int32 CastToInt(System.String)' on the type 'Zx.Data.zxEntities' cannot be translated into a LINQ to Entities store expression because the instance over which it is invoked is not the ObjectContext over which the query in which it is used is evaluated.

.edmx file declaration:

```
<!-- CSDL content -->
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="zxModel" Alias="Self" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
  <!-- blah-blah-blah -->
  <Function Name="CastToInt" ReturnType="Edm.Int32" >
    <Parameter Name="p" Type="Edm.String" />
    <DefiningExpression>
      CAST (p AS Edm.Int32)
    </DefiningExpression>
  </Function>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
```

.Net function declaration:

```
namespace Zx.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Objects;
    using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;

    public partial class zxEntities  
    {
        [EdmFunction("zxModel", "CastToInt")]
        public int CastToInt(String p)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("This function is only for L2E query.");
        }
    }
}
```

calling function:

```
var suppliers = entities.tblFirmPrice.Where(x => x.cat_Id == item.Cat_id)
    .Join(entities.Firms, fp => fp.frm_Id, f => f.Frm_Id,
        (fp, f) => new
        {
            fp.frm_Id,
            Price = fp.fp_FirmPrice,
            Discount = entities.tblFirmDiscount.Where(
                       x => entities.CastToInt(x.frm_id) == fp.frm_Id)
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x.fd_id)
                       .Select(x => x.fd_discount)
                       .FirstOrDefault(),
            PriceMarkup = entities.CastToInt(
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert(f.Frm_IcsAdd))
        })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.frm_Id,
            Price = x.Price * (1 - ((((int?)x.Discount) ?? 0) / 100M)),
            x.PriceMarkup
        });
```

:-(
any suggestions?

P.S.: while coding, used http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

Comment: made a temporary mesaure - computed columns, returning desired data converted to int. but it seems to me is not good way to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Convert.ToInt32 method?

```
Discount = entities.tblFirmDiscount.Where(
              x => Convert.ToInt32(x.frm_id) == fp.frm_Id)
```

Comment: the err msg is: **LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32 (System.String)', and this method can not be translated into a store expression.**

Comment: @rmrfhome: Another option is to do the opposite, i.e., convert `fp.frm_Id` to a `string` and then compare with `x.frm_id`

Comment: the problem is 
            PriceMarkup = entities.CastToInt(
                          SqlFunctions.StringConvert(f.Frm_IcsAdd))
shoud be better int, because the result take part in union further (Frm_IcsAdd is decimal)